# `base64 --decode` doesn't replace variable by the value as `echo` does

Tags: bash, shell, base64

I use the user data of AWS ec2 template/instance.
For that, I'm converting my file into a base64 to be easier to manipulate.

Nevertheless, it doesn't get expanded by the shell/bash with the variable's value.

For the example, I reduced as a simple variable.

`JHtMRVNTT1BFTn0gIG9yICRMRVNTT1BFTg==` is decoded to `${LESSOPEN}  or $LESSOPEN`

```
export LESSOPEN=Hereishtevalue
echo JHtMRVNTT1BFTn0gIG9yICRMRVNTT1BFTg== | base64 --decode
```

- Result:

  - `>${LESSOPEN}  or $LESSOPEN` (I'm not sure which one should work)
- Expected:

  - `>Hereishtevalue  or Hereishtevalue`

Why aren't `$LESSOPEN` and/or `${LESSOPEN}` replaced by the value?

- The goal is to do something like: `echo JHtMRVNTT1BFTn0gIG9yICRMRVNTT1BFTg== | base64 --decode > myfile.txt`

How to fix it?

*The base64 file would be a file template with values depending on the variable defined in the user data of the EC2 template/instance.*

Comment: I can't understand your question correctly. What's the expected output? Which command works and which command doesn't?

Comment: actually it's not echo which replace variable but the shell, see parameter expansion, the phase occurs when the shell is reading command ; decoding `JHtMRVNTT1BFTn0gIG9yICRMRVNTT1BFTg==` gives the literal `${LESSOPEN}`, could be reinterpreted with eval but it's risky because evaluating arbitrary string may lead to unexpected results

Comment: @brunorey I edited my question

Comment: @Nahuel Fouilleul what's the best way to get the expected result then?

Answer (score 1):

Following comments the parameter expansion already occured so the string contains literally `${LESSOPEN}`.

Using eval would lead to security problem because could execute arbitrary code. A workaround is to check the string matches a pattern and use variable indirection, for example.

```
variable=123
input='${variable}'
if [[ $input =~ \${([_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)} ]]; then
    output=${!BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "${output}"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks but that's too hacky, I'll try to find another approach. Having multi-lines string depending on variables' value shouldn't be so complicated.